# Java - Filter before copy file from one server to another

Tags: java, ftp, sftp

I need advice on the best way to copy file from one server to another using Java programming. My program will only copy file only if the file name is not exist in db table. Right now, my program will compare one by one from remote path with data in table. It take long time if there's lot of file to be compare. So, what is the best method or way to do it properly without consuming to much time?

Example of my code :

```
>        if(remoteFile.length > 0){
>             for(int i = 0;i < remoteFile.length;i++){
>                 fileNm = remoteFile[i].getName();
>                 checktable();
>                 if(checktable.getNumberOfRows()==0){
>                     ftp.copyFileFrom("/"+fileNm , filePath);
>                     inserttable();
>                 }
>             }
>         }
```

Comment: There's no better way. Though you may have implemented it inefficiently. Hard to tell, as you didn't show us any code.

Comment: Your code does not show where you got `remoteFile` from. Neither we know what library are you using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsch` to connect to remote path.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session sshSession = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
        sshSession.setPassword(passwd);
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        sshSession.setConfig(config);
        sshSession.connect();
```

Open new SFTP channel , access to your path and list out list of file using extension filer(ex: *.csv)

```
     ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) sshSession.openChannel("sftp");
            sftpChannel.connect();
            sftpChannel.cd(path);
      Vector<LsEntry> fileList = sftpChannel.ls("*.csv");
```

Then you can compare your file list with table's data before copying to your target.

Comment: that mean the process is still comparing the file one by one right? For connect to remote path, i already able to do it. Just need a more simpler way on comparing the file. @htpvl